# Android Firestore Multiple value Query with sorting timestamp Descending

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want query in Firestore database where post author equals current user [this part works fine]. and I want to sorting post with timestamp and order by `DESCENDING`.

Is it possible? Or what is the error of my code?

```
        Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts")
                .whereEqualTo("user_id", current_user_id)
                .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(3);

    firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {


            assert queryDocumentSnapshots != null;
            if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                if(isFirstPageFirstLoad){

                    lastVisible = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                }

                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                        String blogPostID = doc.getDocument().getId();

                        BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class).withId(blogPostID);

                        if(isFirstPageFirstLoad){
                            blog_list.add(blogPost);
                        }
                        else {
                            blog_list.add(0, blogPost);
                        }


                        blogPostHomeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

                isFirstPageFirstLoad = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

**Logcat Error:**

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
```

Database:

[Database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGGy7.png)

Comment: None of the code you shared calls `isEmpty`, so this can't be the source of the error message. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to maximize the chances that we can help.

Comment: Please add your database structure and responde with @.

Comment: I'm attach database design. @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation regarding [onEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/EventListener.html#onEvent(T,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException)) method is mentioned that:

> `onEvent` will be called with the new value or the error if an error occurred. It's guaranteed that **exactly one of value or error will be non-null**.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **value:**    The value of the event. null if there was an error.
>
> **error:**    The error if there was error. null otherwise.

Which basically means that the `onEvent()` method either gets an error or a query snapshot. To solve this, you need an `if-else statement` that might look like this:

```
public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException exception) {
    if (exception != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + exception.getMessage());
    } else {
        for (DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
            //Your logic
        }
    }
});
```